# Re-Indexing in SOLR

Tags: indexing, solr

Does **Solr** re-index every time I add a document?Or does re-indexing occurs only if I change my schema ? If re-indexing occurs only when I change my schema then how does the data gets added to the solr index?

Comment: If by re-indexing you mean indexing all your documents over again, then no, Solr doesn't reindex when you add or delete a document. If you change your schema then any changes that you made will not be reflected in a search until you reindex.

Comment: OK got it.So exactly how does the new data gets added in the existing inverted index?Is it some sort of a incremental update of the inverted index?

Comment: If a document is added, the appropriate entries are inserted into the index (the existing one) referencing the new document. If a document is deleted, the document is marked as deleted and excluded from the resultset (until optimize is called, when the documents are actually purged).